# Issue with loading Angular $window

Tags: angularjs

Hi I'm trying to use $window object in the module below.

```
var testInterceptor = function($provide,$httpProvider,$window){
    // actual Code
}

angular.module('MyApp')
    .config(testInterceptor);
```

But the page is throwing the error like below

**Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module MyApp due to:
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $window**

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: You can't use that in the config phase.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`$window` is a service and can't be used in **config phase**.
Only **providers** and **constants** can be used here.

Read the documentation. https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module

> **Configuration blocks** - get executed during the provider registrations and configuration phase. Only providers and constants can be injected into configuration blocks. This is to prevent accidental instantiation of services before they have been fully configured.

What you could do is place your necessary code in the run phase. Because you can use services here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. (http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jWRmqZ)

```
var testInterceptor = function($provide,$httpProvider,$window){
   // More Code
}

angular.module('MyApp', [])
   .config(['$provide','$httpProvider','$window', testInterceptor]);
```